# How to setup in-memory outbox in asp.net and bind it to ef context's SaveChanges

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, masstransit

I'm having this setup

- asp.net core (2.1)
- ef core (2.1)
- masstransit (5.1)

During a controller action where I do both database changes and publishing events, I would like to hold the outgoing messages in an in-memory outbox until I know that the EF context transaction is successfully committed to the database.

I'm willing to take the risk that the sending then fails, but as that's close to zero compared to db transactions failing due to e.g. concurrency exceptions I don't see it as a risk worth considering in my case.

Is this somehow possible to setup with the current `UseInMemoryOutbox` implementation?
Or do I have to roll my own outbox table [like discussed in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312634/537842) and save the messages to be sent in the same db transaction and then have a background worker polling that table and sending outgoing messages to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to send a command to a queue (via MT, using a send endpoint) in the controller action, and then use a consumer to (1) pull the message from the queue, (2) use the in-memory outbox for events, and (3) insert the relevant data into the database. That way, the controller isn't dependent upon database latency *and* the message queue to produce events. And the command is more durably processed by the consumer, allowing the API controller to quickly return a Http/201 Accepted response code.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's one way to approach the problem, but how do I then signal the UI that the action actually is processed or failed? As the users of this application needs to know that all went well before they can continue with the next task.

Comment: Your consumer can respond, and your controller can use the request client and await the response from the consumer. http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html

Comment: True, didn't think about that. What if the consumer is a Saga though? Can that respond too? Edit: I suppose I can simply just use `context.RespondAsync<>()` method inside the Saga too...

Comment: Yes, there is a .Respond() extension in the state machine to respond to requests.